# Finding a formula for function f

Tags: problem-solving

I need to find a formula for $f(x)$.

The only information about $f$ is:

$\forall x \in {\rm I\!R}, f(\frac{69x}{1+x}) = x^2$

I am clueless about this one.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hint: you know $f(g(x)) = x^2$. Find the inverse $g^{-1}$ of $g$, then $f(g(g^{-1}(x))) = (g^{-1}(x))^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
y = \frac{69x}{1+x} & \Rightarrow y + xy = 69x\\\\
& \Rightarrow x(y - 69) = -y\\\\
& \Rightarrow x = \frac{y}{69 - y}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $$x=\frac {t}{69-t}$$
Your final answer shall be $f(x)=\left(\frac {x}{69-x}\right)^2$